# replacement of values in a dataframe using a double column condition

Tags: r, dataframe, replace

I have the following situation: 
A dataframe df having the following structure

```
Code    Value   Step1   Step2   Step3
123     1       2       4       0
234     2       9       1       4
799     4       0       0       0
311     9       1       2       0
```

I need a way to obtain the following situation in another dataframe without using loops and having great performances due to the fact that the real data frame has 8 starting steps and about 23 millions of rows:
Substitution of the number in the Stepx Columns with the values in the Code column matching the column value and substituting the first 0 with the Code column value, obtaining the following:

```
Code    Value   Step1   Step2   Step3   Step4
123     1       234     799     123     0
234     2       311     123     799     234
799     4       799     0       0       0
311     9       123     234     311     0
```

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, it was a mistake, I edited the right situation, 23 m of rows and 7 columns of steps in the starting data frame , and i should have as result the same number of rows and 1 additional column thanks for the comment

Comment: If the original dataset has 23 million rows, are there as many Codes with corresponding Values? If not, how are the Codes and Values displayed in your data? Right now they each have their own column, is it like that in your data?

Comment: @Leo The answer to your question is Yes, the Code column in the real situation can assume values starting from 1000 up to 5 billions

Comment: did you achieve this already with a loop and just want another solution without one, or haven't you solved it yet at all?

Comment: Already solved in a sort of C program with a loop scanning the steps and for each element  making another search in the value column and when found taking the code and replacing, but it takes ages,

Comment: Why are there 4 steps when there are only 3 steps in the data.

Answer (score 0):

Here's partial solution:

```
require(data.table)

x <- data.table(Code = c(123, 234, 799, 311),
                value = c(1,2,4,9),
                Step1 = c(2,9,0,1),
                Step2 = c(4,1,0,2),
                Step3 = c(0,4,0,0),
                Step4 = c(0,0,0,0))

x[,grep("^Step", colnames(x), value = T):=lapply(x[,grep("^Step", colnames(x), value = T), with = F], function(val) x$Code[match(val, x$value)])]
x[is.na(x)] <- 0

first_null <- apply(x[,grep("^Step", colnames(x), value = T), with = F], 1, function(val) min(which(val == 0)))
```

It does the replace for every "StepX". However, replacing first null row-wise is somewhat tricky to implement without resorting to `for` loop. I gave it a shot and wrote another apply to determine on which step the null has to be replaced for every row... but fail to think of a way to do it in elegant way.

If no other replies, I might try to crack this nut a bit later on.

Comment: [R] base code for the part you solved so far would be: `df1[,grep("^Step", colnames(df1), value = T] <- lapply(df1[,grep("^Step", colnames(df1), value = T], function(x) {x1 <- df1$Code[match(x, df1$Value)]; replace(x1, is.na(x1), 0)})` (Credit to @akrun) and then `first_null <- sapply(apply(df1[,grep("^Step", colnames(df1), value = T)], 1, function(x) which(x == 0)), function(x) {x[1]})`. I agree that a vectorized solution seems unlikely. Maybe a nested `apply`-call over rows and then columns using something like `cumsum`?

Comment: I tried nested applies with transforming StepX matrix into string vectors, then trying to replace first zero with simple `sub()`...and then converting whole thing back to numerics, but somehow it got fairly messy and didn't want to work properly. I think going the route of finding position indexes (which I did) and then replacing values within matrix by their coordinates (I can think only a `for` loop here) will be faster.

Comment: Also... it's kind of subjective off-topic but after working with `data.table`, eventually I somehow found `data.frame` redundant. Hence no base solution.

Comment: Yep, I agree. And when the `for`-loop is only used to replace values by coordinates, it should be relatively fast even on a huge dataset. You could also use the coordinates to obtain the additional column by inserting `0` for every line that had a replacement coordinate, and inserting the `Code`-value of the row there was no coordinate found inside the `Step`-variables.